Hook into Gutenberg mobile layout?
I would like to modify the layout of the WordPress navigation on mobile.
Are there any ways to do this via PHP?
Specifically, I’m referring to the container .wp-block-navigation__responsive-container
Currently, I’m modifying the DOM using SCSS and JavaScript, but I would prefer to change the rendering directly.
If that’s possible, I’d appreciate a brief guide in the right direction.
Is is possible to select another navigation for mobile?
Updated at 10-30-2024:
Yes, I have created a custom menu item that expands my menu with a mega menu.
My current menu structure is:

Home (Page)
About (Page)
Themes (Page)
Test 1 (Custom Menu Item)

As a result, on mobile, my menu item "Test 1" appears as a link to my mega menu. However, I don't want this; instead, I'd like the links to appear as a dropdown.
For mobile, I would like to use a completely different navigation structure.

it is always wrong to try to detect user's device on server side. JS is the way

what are you trying to achieve that requires this? Are you trying to insert things? Remove things? Modify things? The context is important here and will determine what answers apply and don't apply

Is there some reason you can't just style it with your SCSS? Why does JS or PHP have to enter the mix?

I'm assuming your want to shift around the content/mark-up for mobile?  You options are 2 different outputs (one for mobile and one for desktop) or stick with the JS the way you're doing.  Adjust the markup so that you can get really specific with your selectors.
